# How to hide a Navigation Panel on my home page that is loaded from _siteLayout.cshtml

Tags: html, css

I utilize a global CSS and a _siteLayout.cshtml.  Within the _siteLayout.cshtml, I am loading a Navigation Panel for every page on my site.  I have the Navigation Panel enclosed within a  wrapper.

How can I hide that Navigation panel on my Default.cshtml, but still display it on every other page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the negative vote.  I am new to coding, this is my first site.  I have tried to search for hiding within CSS, but then since the Nav Panel is called within _siteLayout.cshtml, don't know how to hide it in my Default.cshtml because it is already loaded from site_Layout.

Comment: You probably got the down vote because you provided no code example at all or explained what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by writing a separate .cshtml for that page, but this would obviously take a while, and disrupt other features, as well as make having a .cshtml relatively useless.  Alternatively, try writing a stylesheet for this page and having it load the Navigation panel behind another element or even have it match the color of the body.  There is probably better solutions, but this has worked for me in the past, so worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Write inline css in your Default.cshtml file.

Ex: if your navigation panel like:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul class="menu">
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Services</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then just put **style="display:none;"** in **`<div id="nav" style="display:none;">`**

if you don't wanna put anything inside div then just put this stylesheet in your Default.cshtml page.

```
<style type="text/stylesheet">
 #nav{display:none;}
 .menu{display:none;} /* this line is optional. you can use any 1 */
</style>
```

Still not work? Just put an important tag inside stylesheet.

```
<style type="text/stylesheet">
 #nav{display:none !important;}
 .menu{display:none !important;} /* this line is optional. you can use any 1 */
</style>
```

If it's inline css then just put `<div id="nav" style="display:none !important;">`

Hope it will works.

Thanks